# Which of these two ways to take the derivative of a delta function times another function is correct?

Tags: functions, physics, derivatives, distribution-theory

A well known identity of the Dirac delta function is that for any function $f(x)$:
$$
 \delta(x) f(x) = \delta(x) f(0).
$$
If we take the derivative of the right hand side we get:
$$
 \delta'(x) f(0).
$$
But if we take the derivative of the left hand side we get
$$
 \delta'(x) f(x) + \delta(x) f'(x) = \delta'(x) f(0) + \delta(x) f'(0)
$$
Which one is correct?

P.S. I know that this problem has something to do with the fact that the delta function is not really a function, but rather a generalized function. However, the delta function and its derivatives are useful in calculations (especially in physics), and I want to know the correct rules for using them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any distribution $T$ can be multiplied with a $C^{\infty}$-function $f$ by the formula $$
(f T)(\varphi) = T(f\varphi) $$ for a test function $\varphi$. And if $T$ has order $0$ like the $\delta$-distribution, $f$ may be a $C^0$-function. And in this sense, the identity $$ f\delta = f(0) \delta$$ is perfectly true.

Applying this multiplication to your left hand side, you have
$$ (f'\delta)(\varphi) + (f\delta')(\varphi) = \delta(f'\varphi) + \delta (-(f\varphi)') = \delta (-f\varphi') = f(0) \delta' (\varphi),$$ your right hand side. So you were perfectly right, you just need to interpret the expression $f\delta'$ correctly as
$$ f\delta' = f(0) \delta' - f'(0) \delta.$$

Comment: It took me a while to understand your answer, but I see now that you are right - thank you. I hope you don't mind I wrote my own answer that explains the same thing in terms that are easier for physicists to understand, anyway I have accepted your answer.

Comment: @Vovo: Dear Vobo, I think it would be helpful if in your answer you also explained that the same method verifies the OP's identity $\delta' f = f(0)\delta' - f'(0) \delta.$ (Of course, it follows from what you wrote and the OP's own manipulations, but it would be good to make it clear.)  Regards,

Comment: @Joe: We typed our answers at the same time, so I didn't see yours, thanks for accepting it anyway, and Matt: I added your hint.

Answer (score 7):

OK I think I know the answer to my own question, and that I can put it in simple terms without getting to much into the mathematical background of delta functions.
My mistake was that I thought the similarly to this identity:
$$
 \delta(x) f(x) = \delta(x) f(0),
$$
which is correct, the following identity is also true:
$$
 \delta'(x) f(x) = \delta'(x) f(0),
$$
but this is **wrong**.
The correct identity is:
$$
 \delta'(x) f(x) = \delta'(x) f(0) - \delta(x) f'(0).
$$
If I use this identity when comparing the two results in the question, they turn out to be the same - meaning *both ways of taking the derivative are correct*.
In fact, the derivation in the question is a proof of this identity.
BTW it is a generalization of the well known identity: $\delta'(x) x = -\delta(x)$

Comment: I consider this the best answer :))

Answer (score 0):

You should define the delta on a proper space of test functions. So,

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta'(x)f(x) \,dx =\left.\delta(x)f(x)\right|_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_{-\infty}^\infty \delta(x)f'(x)\,dx =-f'(0)$$

after integration by parts and where use has been made of the fact that test function $f(x)$ goes enough rapidly to 0 at $\pm\infty$. Manipulations on distribution are only meaningful in this sense.

Comment: Dear Jon, You are not answering the OP's question.  See my comment on Rasmus's answer.  Regards,

Comment: @MattE: Sorry, my hands were faster than my mind.

Comment: Dear Jon, No worries! Best wishes,

Answer (score 0):

The way you wrote the first equation is very misleading and it seems that it caused your confusion. I would prefer to write $\delta(f)=f(0)$. The correct formular for the derivative of $\delta$ is the following
$$
\delta'(f)=-f'(0).
$$
For an explanation, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_distribution#Distributional_derivatives).

Comment: I understand that when you write $\delta'(f)=-f'(0)$ you mean what I would write as $\delta'(x)f(x)=-\delta(x)f'(0)$, but in fact there is another factor of $\delta'(x)f(0)$ which you left out (see [my answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/100507/10314)).

Comment: Dear Rasmus, I have downvoted his answer because it does not deal with the OP's question.  When you write $\delta(f)$, this is what the OP would denote by $\int \delta(x) f(x) dx$.  Hence your formula for $\delta'(f)$ is what the OP would denote by $\int \delta'(x) f(x) dx$.  However, the OP is not asking about the values of these expressions after integrating them; he wants to know the actual values of the expressions themselves.  Regards,

Comment: @Joe: Dear Joe, Hopefully my comment above will  clarify what Rasmus is saying in his answer, and how it relates to what you are asking.  Regards,

Comment: Yes it does, thank you @MattE.

Comment: Dear @Matt, thanks for clarifying. I thought I guessed correctly on what the OP was asking, but obviously I didn't. I'm not even sure I do now--what is the meaning of the symbol $\delta(x)$ for $x\in\mathbb R$? This seems to be similar to the usual confusion concerning the difference between a function and its values. Only that in this context, the value isn't even defined.

Comment: Dear Rasmus,  By $\delta(x)$ the OP just means the delta function (thought of a distribution, say).  The product $\delta(x) f(x)$, or just $\delta f $ if you prefer, is a distribution defined (as in Vobo's answer) by the  formula $\langle \delta f, \varphi\rangle = \langle \delta, f \varphi \rangle.$ (Here the brackets denote the usual pairing between distributions and test functions.)  Regards,